# Why my View localization failed in .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I followed the Globalization and localization tutorial by Microsoft in https://youtu.be/IAegSBI5lPk?t=2277

And here is my code

`startup.cs`:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc()
                .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix,
                options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");            
            services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.      
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            }
            var SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> {
                new CultureInfo("en"),
                new CultureInfo("zh-Hans"),
                new CultureInfo("zh-Hant")
        };
            var options = new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en"),
                SupportedCultures = SupportedCultures,
                SupportedUICultures = SupportedCultures
            };
            app.UseRequestLocalization(options);
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

`index.cshtml`:

```
@page
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
@Localizer["TitleString"]
```

Here is the file list:
[image]

And here is the detial of `Index.en.resx`

[image]

Finally when it runs,it turns out to be this:
[image]

The `@Localizer["TitleString"]` do not display 'HelloWorld' correctly but display 'TitleString'.
I think maybe I am missing something,but I don't konw what is the problem.

Would you please like to help me?Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource file naming and placement is crucial for correct locating of corresponding resources. You set `ResourcesPath` to `Resources` directory. You should put it not under `Pages` but in the project root (on the same level where `Pages` directory resides). Then you should either name resource file `Pages.Index.en.resx` or put it inside `Resources/Pages` subdirectory. Here is the correct placement of resource file for Index page:

[image]

or

[image]

If you want to keep `Resources` directory under `Pages` as in question, you should set `ResourcesPath` to `Pages/Resources`:

```cs
services.AddMvc()
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix,
        options => options.ResourcesPath = "Pages/Resources");
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Pages/Resources");
```

But in this case you should still name resource file properly (`Pages/Resources/Pages.Index.en.resx` or `Pages/Resources/Pages/Index.en.resx`):

[image]

Check [Resource file naming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1#resource-file-naming) section from [Globalization and localization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1) article for more details.

Comment: I am afraid to reply you so late for time difference.I tried the first way and  it worked.But when I tried the second way which set ResourcesPath to Pages/Resources and found it no worked.

Comment: Have you named resource file properly (`Pages/Resources/Pages/Index.en.resx`)? Check 3rd screenshot in my answer.

Comment: I forgot rename the resources name,now it worked.Thank you.